# How to capture n lines before and after a first occurrence of a string match

Tags: grep, centos

Answer with repeated occurrence is like below

```
[root@centos6 bin]# grep -A 2 -B 2 "SampleTextFile.txt" /var/log/messages
Nov 10 00:14:54 centos6 kernel: Kernel logging (proc) stopped.
Nov 10 00:14:54 centos6 rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="5.8.10" x-pid="1513" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] exiting on signal 15.
File SampleTextFile.txt
First Line after original SampleTextFile.txt
Nov 12 18:13:48 centos6 kernel: imklog 5.8.10, log source = /proc/kmsg started.
Nov 12 18:13:48 centos6 rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="5.8.10" x-pid="1519" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
--
Nov 12 18:14:19 centos6 polkitd[2382]: started daemon version 0.96 using authority implementation `local' version `0.96'
Nov 12 18:14:19 centos6 rtkit-daemon[2388]: Sucessfully made thread 2386 of process 2386 (/usr/bin/pulseaudio) owned by '42' high priority at nice level -11.
File SampleTextFile.txt
Second Line after original SampleTextFile.txt
Nov 12 18:14:19 centos6 pulseaudio[2386]: alsa-util.c: Disabling timer-based scheduling because running inside a VM.
Nov 12 18:14:19 centos6 rtkit-daemon[2388]: Sucessfully made thread 2392 of process 2386 (/usr/bin/pulseaudio) owned by '42' RT at priority 5.
[root@centos6 bin]#
```

If I use -m switch then it doe not show "AFTER" lines...

```
[root@centos6 bin]# grep -m 1 -A 2 -B 2 "SampleTextFile.txt" /var/log/messages
Nov 10 00:14:54 centos6 kernel: Kernel logging (proc) stopped.
Nov 10 00:14:54 centos6 rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="5.8.10" x-pid="1513" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] exiting on signal 15.
File SampleTextFile.txt
[root@centos6 bin]#
```

My grep version is below:

```
[root@centos6 bin]# grep -V
grep (GNU grep) 2.20
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Mike Haertel and others, see <http://git.sv.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/tree/AUTHORS>.
[root@centos6 bin]#
```

I would sincerely appreciate any help to solve this issue.

Thank you in advance.

--Edit:

Expected result

```
 [root@centos6 bin]# grep -A 2 -B 2 "SampleTextFile.txt" /var/log/messages
    Nov 10 00:14:54 centos6 kernel: Kernel logging (proc) stopped.
    Nov 10 00:14:54 centos6 rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="5.8.10" x-pid="1513" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] exiting on signal 15.
    File SampleTextFile.txt
    First Line after original SampleTextFile.txt
    Nov 12 18:13:48 centos6 kernel: imklog 5.8.10, log source = /proc/kmsg started.
    Nov 12 18:13:48 centos6 rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="5.8.10" x-pid="1519" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
```

Comment: `grep -B2 -A2 -m2 "something" messages | head -5` maybe?

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: I prefer not to use pipes, one old Linux Guru told me sometime back to refrain from using pipes as much as possible, not good with awk but maybe awk would be of any help ?

Comment: @learner, the fact that *one old Linux Guru told me sometime back to refrain from using pipes as much as possible* - does not mean you should refuse using pipes in any situation